# ESXi VM re-adding

Tags: vmware-esxi

I have an HP Microserver running ESXi 6.5 from a USB stick. A series of power outages seems to have caused some corruption, preventing ESXi from booting (pink screen, unable to load kernel modules).

The VMs reside on a mirrored pair of HDDs so should hopefully still be intact and healthy.

I've done a fresh install of ESXi on a new stick and was wondering if it's possible to point ESXi to the VMs sitting on the drive array so it can manage them again?

Answer (score 0):

Seems it's actually very straightforward - just navigate to the storage array the VMs are sitting on and use the 'Register a VM' button at the top.

Comment: You can also browse the datastore, right click a VMX file for a VM and select "Register VM".